# ASP NET SQL - for each row create a new div

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, foreach

Looking for a solution to create a new div with its content for each row in SQL Server database table:

```
Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select Date,Title,Content from Log where Author = @Author", con)
com.Parameters.Add("@Author", SqlDbType.Char)
com.Parameters("@Author").Value = User.Identity.Name

Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

For Each Datarow In dt.Rows
       //create New div with its content
Next
```

This one is working, but can't get it to create a new div/table with its content yet.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The usual way to do this in Web Forms is to bind your DataTable to some sort of control such as a Repeater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select Date,Title,Content from Log where Author = @Author", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sasa"].ConnectionString);
 da1.Fill(ds);
 string makehtml = string.Empty;
//however when you have DataSet then you can iterate easily and cerate whatever you want
    for(int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        makehtml += "<div><span>Date:</span> " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"] + " <span>Title:</span> " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Title"] + "< span > Content:</ span > " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Content"] + " </div>";
    }
```

Please check if it helps. i am not expert in VB but when you have DataSet then you can iterate over the DataSet Row by Row and create a div or have some other operations to perform.
Some Other options or good approach:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lstVDataBind" runat="server">
                                    <LayoutTemplate>
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                                    </LayoutTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="col-md-12"><span>Date:</span><%#Eval("Date")%>
                                            <span>Title:</span><%#Eval("Title")%>< span > Content:</ span > <%#Eval("Content")%></div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
```

And in code behind you can assign your dataset to Listview as datasource like:

```
lstVDataBind.DataSource = ds;
        lstVDataBind.DataBind();
```

You can also use repeater instead of Listview.
Another way you can do samething:

```
 <%-- statrt here --%>
            <% if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {%>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-12"><span>Date:</span><%=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"].ToString()%>
                <span>Title:</span><%=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Title"].ToString()%><span> Content:</span><%=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Content"].ToString()%></div>
            </div>
            <%}} %>
            <%-- Ends here --%>
```

This code will be in aspx page but for this you have to make your dataset public so it be easilty accessible.

Comment: Do you know how I can apply css styles to the divs? like this

Comment: `makehtml += "<div class='panel-group'"`

the css style wont apply:/

Comment: css will work normally. either you are using style attribute or you can use a css class. like: 
     <div style="font-size:12px;"></div>
     <div class='col-md-12'></div>

Comment: @Luke send an example then i will understand your css problem exactly..if css class is not working then try with inline css.

Comment: This is really a terrible way of going about adding repeated content to a webpage in Web Forms.

Comment: @mason Thanks. you are right, anyway, i edited the answer. try to approve.

Comment: I have removed the downvote. Your answer could still use a lot of formatting work - you have an excessive amount of whitespace in your code that really harms readability. I suggest you clean that up.

Comment: Hi @UsmanMirza - I used your listview method, but I'm wondering how to delete a row.

Comment: `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Delete()`
`ds.AcceptChanges()`

this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select Date,Title,Content from Log where Author = @Author", con)
com.Parameters.Add("@Author", SqlDbType.Char)
com.Parameters("@Author").Value = User.Identity.Name

Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

Dim _div As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
Dim _label As New HtmlGenericControl("label") ' for example that content you want to display is the fullname, for my example i will use label tag
Dim _indx As Integer = 0
For Each row In dt.Rows
   _div  = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
   _div .ID = "div" & _indx.toString().trim
   _div .Attributes.Add("class", "your class that you want to add") ' optional only if you want
   _label = New HtmlGenericControl("label")
   _label.ID = "lbl" & _indx.toString().trim
   _label.InnerText = row("name of the field in your dt ex. fullname").toString().trim
   _div .Controls.Add(_label)
   _pnl1.Controls.Add(_div)
Next

.. In the design page

<body>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server"> <!-- you can use panel to properly place your dynamic div -->

    </asp:Panel>


</body>
```

.. hope this code help